# Flexible adding new features to base object

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have some listing where the User objects are listed. The base object has methods:

```
final class User
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $id, string $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

But I have some exceptional listing which requires additional data for User (so I'd like to add new methods (new features - please notice final class) to this User object). For example, getting Phone - but I'd like to do it flexible - I'd like later add for example another method (for example getFriends). But I'd like to choose which features should be available in listing - something like decorator but not completely.

How to do it "by the book"? The decorator pattern is not appropriate here because I change the interface of the object.

Maybe my approach is wrong and I should handle this in the other way?

Comment: It's impossible to give you a full, unequivocal answer, but the decorator seems to fit the bill for this use case. Not sure why you say it's not appropriate. The decorator needs to implement the interface of the decorated, but it can **add** to that interface, or modify the behaviour of existing methods.

Comment: @yivi Decorator is not appropriate here, because for example I decorate User Object with Phone decorator which gives getPhone method and this object I'd like to decorate with Friends decorator which gives getFriends method - in that way I lost access to getPhone method. So decorator has to keep the interface. Of course some kind of decorator would be good but only on one level, next decorations cause lost earlier decorations.